# How can a process detect that it's in a child namespace?

Tags: linux, debian, docker, namespace, container

I have researched the subject and found the following code on Github, which says:

```
// HasNamespace determines if a container is using a particular namespace or the
// host namespace.
// The device number of an unnamespaced /proc/1/ns/{ns} is 4 and anything else is
// higher.
// Only works from inside a container.
```

https://github.com/genuinetools/amicontained/blob/568b0d35e60cb2bfc228ecade8b0ba62c49a906a/vendor/github.com/jessfraz/bpfd/proc/proc.go#L461

However, that comment is obsolete, which is demonstrated by:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm --pid host debian
root@e29ab2d7176b:/# stat --format="%d" /proc/self/ns/net
58
root@e29ab2d7176b:/# stat --format="%d" /proc/self/ns/pid
58
```

Here `stat --format="%d" /proc/self/ns/pid` should result in 4, if that comment was correct.

How can a process detect whether it's in a child namespace?

Comment: @A.B - thanks. Yes, I know there are several kinds of namespaces. That’s why I didn’t mention a specific namespace type in the question. If you don’t know a general way to detect a child namespace for all namespace types, will you then show a heuristic for a single namespace type? I don’t have a specific use case, except patching the `amicontained` container profiling tool.

Comment: @A.B - thanks. How do you check the first heuristic for PID 2 (and why is PID 2 of special interest)? Will you show commands? Your user namespace heuristic is currently used by `amicontained`, but that’s the only non-generic heuristic used (all other namespaces are checked by device number, which as I’ve demonstrated fails).

Comment: That check based on "device" number 4 done by `amicontained` cannot check for arbitrary namespaces. At best it can only check whether the _PID_ namespace is a child or not. In fact, AFAICT (not a Go expert I am) that `HasNamespace` function seems to be [invoked only once and for the `pid` namespace only](https://github.com/genuinetools/amicontained/blob/568b0d35e60cb2bfc228ecade8b0ba62c49a906a/main.go#L60). IOW it doesn't seem to be meant to detect arbitrary namespaces, it seems to be meant to infer a containerization just because containers _typically_ bring along a dedicated PID namespace.

Comment: Besides, device numbers for pseudo filesystems can (and do) change but `58` is quite a lot different from `4`. Are you sure you've executed that `docker run [...] --pid host` command from the _bare host_ OS, and not from an already-child namespace or _containerized_ OS? weren't you by any chance using a docker-in-docker or perhaps LXC setup?

Comment: @LL3 - thanks. Yes, I executed `docker run -ti --rm --pid host debian` on both macOS and Linux VM (Parallels) and `stat --format="%d" /proc/self/ns/pid` results in 5 and 74, respectively. Why are device numbers of interest? Namespaces are not pseudo filesystems, are they? Indeed, cgroups are pseudo filesystems. If the device number strategy works (or worked) for the PID namespace, wouldn't it work for other namespaces too?

Comment: Exactly, they are not of interest for namespaces. It may work for PID namespaces only because every PID namespace is tightly bound to its own instance of `proc` filesystem, and each such instance has its own (dynamic) "device" value. It used to be 3 for kernels v3, 4 for kernels v4, it now seems to be 5 for kernels v5. Not sure whether that's incidental or deliberate. In any case "device" numbers for pseudo fs are dynamic, hence not to be relied upon.

Comment: my initial namespace gets 21, not 5. So it's not just a matter of kernel. Perhaps a matter of dynamic pseudo-device creation during boot

Comment: @A.B Yep, very likely indeed. #Shuzheng The thing is that detecting a containerization engine (like Docker, LXC, etc.) _as a whole_ may be easy, but telling whether an arbitrary _raw namespace_ is a child namespace or not is a lot trickier. Maybe something that is not even _supposed_ to be possible.

Comment: In lack of authoritative answers perhaps I'll post a pseudo-answer myself to demonstrate how tricky and/or "unsupported" such detection is

Comment: @LL3 - I will be happy for such an (pseudo) answer :-) I guess only a kernel developer can give a definite answer.

Comment: @LL3 - So, namespaces besides the PID namespace (via its mounted `/proc`) are not associated with device numbers, right? So, `amicontained` relied on the assumption that`/proc` had device number 5 for Linux v5.x kernel, and other `/proc` mounts needed to have higher device numbers to be unique? This assumption doesn’t hold anymore?

Comment: @LL3 - why doesn’t `amicontained` read the device number of `/proc` then instead of the device number of `/proc/1/ns/pid`? I guess it doesn’t matter because all files on the `/proc` share the same device number?

Comment: @Shuzheng Yes, I really can't see any good reason why to do `lstat(2)` on `/proc/1/ns/pid`. Besides, that one may even be inaccessible. Better look at `/proc` itself which to an `lstat(2)` would return the same device value as `/proc/1/ns/pid`. Different story would be to `stat(2)` instead of `lstat(2)`, but that's not what that `HasNamespace` function is doing. For the other questions I think I have answered in the answer posted just now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can share what I found out some time ago when I researched the subject myself. It's certainly not authoritative nor exhaustive but it may be of some help.

#### Technical description

**Disclaimer note**

I myself have never actually implemented any of the approaches that I am about to describe. They are just possibilities I pondered for a custom containerization project I worked on some time ago, but then decided to drop namespace detection completely. If anyhow interested, read on.

---

This is an approach to detect initial namespaces by leveraging observed behaviors by the kernel. (But **beware these behaviors are not official API**). This approach would work under most common & sane setups, though they may not always be the case.

**"Boot" namespaces**

Starting from [kernel v3.8](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/proc_fs.h?h=v3.8#n32) up to the current latest stable [v5.11](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/proc_ns.h?h=v5.11.11#n43) (and current v5.12-rc), the *initial* IPC, UTS, user, PID, cgroup, and time namespaces always have a specific hardcoded ID as listed below. Therefore we can safely assume that for *those* namespace types any namespace ID greater than the fixed ones may be considered child namespaces:

```c
IPC    = 0xEFFFFFFF
UTS    = 0xEFFFFFFE
USER   = 0xEFFFFFFD
PID    = 0xEFFFFFFC
CGROUP = 0xEFFFFFFB
TIME   = 0xEFFFFFFA
```

The above list is taken from v5.12-rc6 sources, but those values have always been the same since v3.8, except of course for the namespaces that did not exist at all in v3.8 ("cgroup" has been added in v4.6, while "time" in v5.6).

Notice how those initial namespaces have been added (over the years) with values "growing" downwards. Conversely, all child namespaces take sequential (on-demand) values [growing upwards from `0xF0000000`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/generic.c?h=v5.11.11#n201).

So, *for setups where no ancestor process overrode initial namespaces*, those fixed values may settle the "quest for detection" of those namespaces quite neatly.

**However, let me reiterate that those values are *not at all* part of any official API exposed to userspace** (not even to kernel-space AFAICT) **hence they may be subject to change in the future**.

The kernel developers might even choose to make them all dynamic or even random. In fact, you may notice that mount and network namespaces are not in that list, and that's because *all* network and mount namespaces, *including* the initial ones, are already entirely dynamic, and *always* take IDs starting from `0xF0000000` just like any child namespace. As a result, for mount and network initial namespaces one must still do some heuristics even under the friendliest conditions.

**Mount namespace**

In my experience so far, I've noticed that the initial mount namespace ID always gets the first dynamic value (`0xF0000000`). Supposedly that's due to the initial PID namespace instantiating the general `proc` filesystem, thus pulling-in the first mount namespace as well. Anyways, the initial mount namespace's ID seems to be easily predictable, being practically fixed even though among the dynamic range.

**Network namespace**

The initial network namespace ID on the other hand gets faraway values and can be different even from previous boots of the same machine with same OS when configuration changes affect the sequence of inode numbers generated dynamically. Therefore, detecting an initial network namespace may become a true lottery. You can "win" it more often than not, but this requires assuming several things that, although they hold true in common sane setups, they do not necessarily always hold.

The first network namespace is instantiated as a consequence of any process (typically PID 1) requesting the first networking operation since system's boot. Hence a `/proc/net/` directory becomes available and files/directories get created therein, each with their own inode number allocated from the same (dynamic) values used for namespace IDs. It so happens (in my experience so far at the time of this writing) that the first name created therein is the `stat` directory. Hence that directory takes the *last* inode number generated *immediately before* the instantiation of the network namespace. The network namespace's own ID is therefore `/proc/net/stat`'s inode number + 1.

Naturally the `/proc/net/stat` directory, being in fact a "namespaced" name itself, as seen by an arbitrary process may not necessarily refer to the *initial* network namespace. It does refer to the initial network namespace when the process accessing that directory *lives* in the initial namespaces (i.e. it is a non-containerized process), but in a containerized environment that would more likely refer to the dedicated network namespace the process belongs to rather than to the initial network namespace.

**Q:** So how can a process try to guess generically whether its network namespace is in fact the initial one?

**A:** By enumerating *recursively* all visible **non-pid** files/dirs within its `/proc` directory to look for inode numbers starting from `0xF0000001` until it encounters the *first* hole of *at least **2*** missing inode numbers.

Many non-pid files/dirs in `/proc` are (to this date) common to all PID namespaces because they are related to kernel's core functionalities (e.g. irq statistics, etc.). The hole in their inode numbers has to be of *at least* 2 **adjacent** numbers because one is for the `/proc/net/stat` directory created for the initial network namespace and one for the initial network namespace itself (also assuming an atomic allocation between the two). In such first hole there *would* lie the initial network namespace's ID. Compare that (hole of) IDs with the process's own (or other arbitrary) network namespace's ID and (in most common cases) you are finally all set at last.

However, even for common cases, it is obvious that we are relying on those non-pid names being *always* visible to *all* PID namespaces *and* sharing the same numbering as the namespaces's IDs *and* being in (nearly) perfect sequence *and* the `/proc/net/*` inode numbers being allocated atomically together the namespace's own ID. All these assumptions *may* hold true now, but may well stop being true in the future simply because that behavior is not at all official API.

In addition, just to further point out how tricky this matter is, note that what is viewed under `/proc` is *always* the PID namespace of the process that *mounted* that *specific* `/proc` directory, hence not necessarily the PID namespace of the process *reading* that `/proc` directory. A discrepancy between "mounter" of `/proc` and "reader" of `/proc` is unlikely to occur in sane practices, but still perfectly possible and easily leading to inconsistent analysis.

---

#### Some opinionated considerations

Except for the initial *user* namespace, whose detection is really easy<sup>1</sup> and also part of an official API, detecting namespaces is a problem that takes a lot of effort to tackle, if at all possible, because there is not a real and comprehensive API supporting it (which is supposedly deliberate for the sake of fuller isolation). A few years ago a couple of [`ioctl(2)` operations have been added to the list for namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ns.2.html), but they are still quite limited and I couldn't fathom any way (not even insane ones) of using them for **definitive** detection purposes.

There are indeed a couple of other simple tricks for detecting PID namespaces too, but they are not official API either. See for instance what the `systemd` people [have discussed also recently](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/17902) for their tools. Apparently they, too, had explored the thing about the `proc` device number being "3 or 4", but dropped that idea because they noticed that it doesn't hold that much (and perhaps it ever held only in "sunny day" conditions however common they may be). They've also explored PID 2 being always `[kthreadd]` and/or overall presence of kernel threads, which would be indisputable sign of initial PID namespace, but they dropped that idea too because mounting `proc` with `hidepid=[12]` would defy that check completely.

I would say that the fundamental problem with detecting namespaces is that they are inherently arbitrary, and can be totally superseded by other namespaces. For all namespace types the kernel does have the so-called "initial" namespaces, but the first PID 1 process (even the one in `initramfs`) may choose to override them by simply `unshare(2)`-ing all (or even just a few) of them before starting any other process. Clearly under such (not too) hypothetical condition, the quest for detecting the initial namespaces loses any useful sense, as it is rather the "host" namespaces that are relevant. Those are the namespaces where the *bare* OS (i.e. the *main* PID 1 `init` process) *operates* in once bootstrapped, even though such "host" namespaces may already be *child* namespaces as far as the kernel is concerned. I'm not saying that `init` processes really override initial namespaces all the time, but in principle they can, and that's enough to cripple any namespace-detection tool.

In my opinion the thing is also that, for most practical use cases, you aren't *really* interested in *arbitrary* namespaces. Almost certainly you are not interested at all in the UTS, IPC, cgroup, and time namespaces, and probably not even in the user and PID namespaces. If ever, you may be interested in just the mount and network namespaces because those are the relevant ones for access to data and to connectivity. The PID namespace is often being looked for a lot only because a PID namespace (much more than a user namespace) typically *implies* a container in its wider sense, and a "wider" container is simply what brings along the interesting mount and network namespaces. Unfortunately these latter are the trickiest to hunt down, which is probably the reason why detection tools prefer to rather look for PID namespaces in hope for a loosely-bound yet good relationship between that and the mount/network namespaces.

To sum it all up with all these "if"s and "but"s and caveats, the matter is whether the effort of trying to detect "initial or child" namespaces worths the while or not. I daresay that it usually doesn't, you're probably better off without detecting them at all, or perhaps with only detecting your narrowed-down definition of what constitutes a "host" namespace for your specific well-defined use cases.

HTH

---

<sup>1. Just read `/proc/self/uid_map` file and see if it reports          `0          0 4294967295` precisely</sup>

Comment: When you say *namespace ID*, you mean the *inode number* as given by e.g. `ls -li /proc/self/ns/pid`? So, namespaces are just files, having symbolic links referencing them from `/proc`, not residing on a file system, but only in the kernel (in a pseudo file system)?

Comment: Why are mount and network namespaces not created by default on boot, i.e. considered *boot namespaces*? Is it because, Linux may function without the mount and network namespace, and so they are only created on-demand?

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, and for sharing your ideas and experiments. I guess, I will use the boot namespaces as a heuristic, besides that I see that other heuristic are extremely fragile and like to break.

Comment: A namespace ID is its inode number as given by `ls -Lli /proc/self/ns/pid` (note the additional `L` option), and also by `stat -Lc %i  /proc/self/ns/pid`, and also by `readlink /proc/self/ns/pid` or simply by `ls -l /proc/self/ns/pid` (in these latter two commands it is the number reported in brackets). As for namespaces being "just files residing only in a kernel pseudo-fs".. it's a good point but I wouldn't push it to that extent. It's just that they get their IDs from the same pool of values also used for the inode numbers of the `proc` pseudo-fs. There ends the analogy with being files.

Comment: As for the motives of making mount/network namespaces dynamic I wouldn't know, but your own suggestion may very well be a good reason and I would bet on that. Note however that "boot" namespaces is just my own term to refer to those namespaces collectively.

Comment: Regarding the reporting of device number 58 for `/proc`, I guess it's not due to `init` having `unshare(2)`'d the PID namespace, since the PID namespace ID is reported as the corresponding hardcoded boot namespace ID.

Comment: I infer from **the quest for detecting the "initial" namespaces loses any useful sense, as it is rather the "host" namespaces that are relevant.** that it's not possible to detect the (non-initial) host namespaces in any sensible way? I only ask, because much of your answer is concerned with the initial namespaces.

Comment: @Shuzheng Not without cooperation by processes living in the "host" namespaces. It is no different than detecting a containerization engine (Docker, LXC, etc.), which is easier because the engine itself deliberately leaves hints around for _its_ child namespaces to perform "detection". My answer is concerned with the "initial-child" dualism because that's what makes sense kernel-wise (and what you asked for). "Host" namespaces that are non-initial are child just like Docker's namespaces are. If child namespaces could autonomously & easily become aware of being child, there'd be no isolation

Comment: @Shuzheng The `systemd` people for instance have apparently decided to completely give up hunting down namespaces, and rather started relying on cgroup hierarchies only, because those are another kernel's subsystem used a lot by containerization engines. (and by `systemd` itself even for the host OS on host/initial namespaces).

Comment: I would say there is still resource isolation although the child namespace become aware that’s a child. “No isolation” is a bit too much to say :-)