# Why is the default NameSpace of pid always 4026531836

Tags: linux, namespace

Why is the default NameSpace of pid always 4026531836.

Whats special about this number?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644209/70524

Comment: To be clear, 0xEFFFFFFC is 4026531836.

Comment: Confirmed that number is hex `0xEFFFFFFC`. Arbitrary large integers are often bit-related. (See 3735928559).